# Put dynamic content cell values into array iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, tableview

I have a `UITableView` which populates dynamically getting data from other source.Now, I want to put that dynamic cell contents into an `NSArray`.

Comment: Encapsulate your data with an object.  Way too broad.  Also, <rant> iOS AND COCOA ARE NOT THE SAME THING </rant>

Comment: ok mean you need all your tableView cell in an array??

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at this the wrong way. You get data from another source. That data should be organized into whatever format you need. You then populate a table with that data.

You do not create arrays from a table view. The table view displays the data (which will typically be organized in an array).

Comment: While I understand that generic answers come from generic questions, this is not technically an answer.  It can be interpreted (albeit liberally), that the OP was asking for, as you put it, how to populate a table from a data source.

Answer (score 0):

From which array u get the data to fill in tableview cell ,using exactly that array globally.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Mutable Array you are using to populate the Table and then reload the table by following code

```
[your_Table reloadData]; //and delegates will do the rest for you.
```